# Why is some of the text in my uiwebview getting cut off?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, safari, ios8

In the next to last line of text in the attached image you will notice that the top of the ruby text annotation is cut off on some of the words.

What can cause this? What should I true in order to fix it?

Let me know if you need more information.

[image: text in rt tags getting cut off]

zoomed in:
[image: zoomed in]

Comment: That's something to do with the markup. Have you checked to see if the same HTML renders correctly in the Safari browser? Might be as simple as updating the line height property in the CSS on the site being displayed in the webview.

Comment: Curious. Why would that cause a problem with only some of the text?

Comment: Without knowing more about the markup, i'm not sure. Possibly the glyphs that make up the language used here are variable in height and mess with the line heights.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/webmagnets/ohxtq0yj/ When I scroll through the result frame in desktop Safari I see a white rectangle that stays in the middle of the screen and covers only the text in the ```<rt>``` tags. Whatever ```<rt>``` tag that goes under it gets cut off. What could this be?

Comment: I don't think the browser wants all that content inside the H1 tags. Try removing the H1 tags and resizing the text with CSS.

Comment: I tried removing all the H1 tags and that "invisible" rectangle is still there.

Comment: I've looked and looked, but the markup is pretty difficult to read. My suggestion would be to pair it down to the absolute essentials and work back up to what you want it to look like without the inline styles and styling specific tags.